# How to tell in PHP that a character is as an other character?

Tags: php, mysql

I will select in my database Nice Cote d'Azur or Nice-Cote-d'Azur, but i am not supposed know if in my database there is written Nice Cote d'Azur without any "-" or Nice-Cote-d'Azur with "-".
And I will must do a select which can select it regardless of if there is a "-" or a " ".

Here an exemple of my code:

```
//worry about this line
$city = $v['City'].replace("-", " ") || $v['City'].replace(" ", "-");

//do the select //don't worry about this line
$CityIATA = $GLOBALS['Db']->Select(SQL_DB_ADMIN .".`CityIATA`", array('City' => $GLOBALS['Db']->Escape($city)))[0]['idIATA'];
```

But it does not work as sheduled. Why ?

An i have `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function replace()`

and how to initialize a variable like a regex ?

```
$nice = "Nice[ -]Cote[ -]d'Azur" ?
```

Comment: PHP isn't Javascript. In PHP you do [`str_replace(.., .., $str)`](http://php.net/str_replace), not `$str.replace(.., ..)`. I'm also not sure what you hope to do in that line with `||`. The real answer is probably that you either want to use a regex `Nice[ -]Cote[ -]d'Azur` to query your database, or you want to do some input normalisation to avoid this situation entirely.

Answer (score 0):

As someone already suggested you are not using the correct php syntax/function.

You can't initialise a var as a regex expression, you can initialise a string which is your pattern. Use a regex when querying the database - see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html